# python time.sleep when executed in python3.5.1 it is telling expected an indented block

Tags: python, time

Where i have to change the settings:

```
import time
import webbrowser

total_break = 3
break_count = 0

 print("this program started on " +time.ctime())

 while(break_count < total_break):
   time.sleep(10)

   webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfAu88n_rac");

 break_count = break_count+1
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Or some problem?

Comment: As you have seen in the error message: indentation matters. Please format your code example.

Comment: If this layout is accurate, then you have unnecessarily and incorrectly indented everything from `print` on. Python is very sensitive to indentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the proper indention:

```
import time
import webbrowser

total_break = 3
break_count = 0

print("this program started on " +time.ctime())

while(break_count < total_break):
    time.sleep(10)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfAu88n_rac");
    break_count = break_count+1
```